# Yii2 Nav widget doesnt support routes with baseUrl

Tags: yii, yii2

1) I have my Yii2 in **subfilder**, so all my link starts from Yii/, like **http:/localhost/Yii/settings/usertype-activitytype/type/3**

2) request component config

```
'request' => [
    'cookieValidationKey' => 'somecookiekey',
    'baseUrl' => '/Yii',
],
```

3) Trying to build Menu, current route is **http:/localhost/Yii/settings/usertype-activitytype/type/1** the 1 is id in route, and I should specify current route as Yii::$app->request->pathInfo for Nav widget

**Attempt 1 - no bracets as string** *NOT FIND ACTIVE ELEMENT*

```
Nav::widget([
            'items' => array_map(function($userType) {
                return [
                    'label' => $userType->name,
                    'url'   => Url::current(['id' => $userType->id]),
                ];
            }, $userTypes),
            'route' => Yii::$app->request->pathInfo,
            'options' => ['class' =>'nav-pills'],
        ]);
```

**Attempt 2 - use bracets as route** *NOT FIND ACTIVE ELEMENT*

```
Nav::widget([
            'items' => array_map(function($userType) {
                return [
                    'label' => $userType->name,
                    'url'   => [Url::current(['id' => $userType->id])]
                ];
            }, $userTypes),
            'route' => Yii::$app->request->pathInfo,
            'options' => ['class' =>'nav-pills'],
        ]);
```

**Attempt 3 - remove baseUrl from generated route** *FIND ACTIVE ELEMENT !!!*

```
Nav::widget([
            'items' => array_map(function($userType) {
                return [
                    'label' => $userType->name,
                    'url'   => [str_replace('Yii/', '', Url::current(['id' => $userType->id]))]
                ];
            }, $userTypes),
            'route' => Yii::$app->request->pathInfo,
            'options' => ['class' =>'nav-pills'],
        ]);
```

So you should notice I **have to use dirty hack to force Nav work with generated Url**, it seems very unconvient.

The question is - ***is there are ways to force NAV widget to recognize current active item*** ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want buil an url based on your param you should use `Url::to()`as

```
'url'   => Url::to(your-controller/your-view', ['id' => $userType->id]),
```

so accessing the view `type` for controller `usertype-activitytype`

```
 'url'   => Url::to('usertype-activitytype/type', ['id' => $userType->id]),
```

current Creates a URL by using the current route and the GET parameters.

and remember that

> By Design UrlManager always prepends base URL to the generated URLs.
>   By default base URL is determined based on the location of entry
>   script. If you want to customize this, you should configure the
>   baseUrl property of UrlManager.

Looking to your comment  the url is correcly formed .. then  if you need  http:/localhost/Yii  instead of Yii then you can:

- don't set so the localhost ... url is atomatically  created
- OR add the proper base url  configureation as http:/localhost/Yii/ in config /main and remember that you can use main.php and main-local.php for manage different congiguration

Comment: This approach not works also, tried like ,'url' => [Url::to(['', 'id' => $userType->id])], also tried like 'url' => [Url::to(['usertype-activitytype/type', 'id' => $userType->id])], is seems like Nav widget tries to compare only route part and ignores baseUrl

Comment: you have error  ?   .. what mean "don't work"?   what is the result provided  by url::to() and the result you expect ? ... is not clear to me your goal

Comment: Nav widget doesnt recognize active item if you have baseUrl setted and url formed through URL::to

Comment: have you tried  to var_dump(Url::to('usertype-activitytype/type', ['id' => $userType->id])) and see the real result  ??

Comment: Ofcourse and generated link looks like /Yii/settings/usertype-activitytype/type/2, and because of Yii/ part Nav widget fails to recognize active element, therefore I used to hack str_replace _Yii_. Seems dirty And if I manually put there a string without Yii/ part it works, and if I add Yii/ part it works not.

Comment: Looking to your sample and your google you could avoid the urlBase or manage properly  .. answer updated  with a brief  suggestion ..

Comment: Well, what I should to do if I really need to Yii been placed in subfolder ?